# (mongodb) Fetching a bson object within a bson object using csharp

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection which contains documents like:

```
{
    field1: {subfield1:{ssfield1:5,ssfield2:6},subfield2:6},
    field2: 1,
    ...
}
```

I'd like to fetch only the subfield, but I'm not sure how to get it querying from csharp (it doesn't seem to return the bsondocument within the bsondocument).

Any help?

I tried this:

```
String c = "mongodb://"+myip;
MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(c);
MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase(mydb);
var collection = db.GetCollection(col); 
string[] fields = new string[] { "field1" };  
MongoCursor cursor = collection.Find().SetFields(fields);
```

but it seems to return

```
{subfield2:6}
```

Comment: try collection.find().first().GetElement("field1").value;

Answer (score 0):

I created a collection with one document very similar to your sample document:

```
> db.test.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("518ac1aa92f1c388279a9979"),
    "field1" : {
        "subfield1" : {
            "ssfield1" : 5,
            "ssfield2" : 6
        },
        "subfield2" : 6
    },
    "field2" : 1
}
>
```

Before showing the result I got when I attempted to reproduce your C# code, let's look at the same query in the MongoDB shell:

```
> db.test.find({}, { field1 : 1 }).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("518ac1aa92f1c388279a9979"),
    "field1" : {
        "subfield1" : {
            "ssfield1" : 5,
            "ssfield2" : 6
        },
        "subfield2" : 6
    }
}
>
```

There are several things to notice here:

1. By default the server always returns the _id field
2. field1 was the only other field returned (just what we asked for)
3. subfield2 was returned because it's embedded in field1

I used slightly different C# code from yours to test:

```
foreach (var document in collection.FindAll().SetFields("field1"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(document.ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings { Indent = true }));
}
```

And the output I got from that loop was:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("518ac1aa92f1c388279a9979"),
  "field1" : {
    "subfield1" : {
      "ssfield1" : 5.0,
      "ssfield2" : 6.0
    },
    "subfield2" : 6.0
  }
}
```

which is essentially identical to the output from the MongoDB shell.

Let me know if you have any further questions.